# How to slice and pile by number of columns a csv file?

Tags: linux, csv

I have a csv file with ~ 2000 columns per row, and I need to slice it up 6 columns.
Once it is slice up, the slices should be piled up.

For example:

```
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2
G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2
```

will become:

```
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1
G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1
A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2
G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2
```

How can I do that from shell command line?

Comment: the initial number of columns should be divisible by `6`. Is that guaranteed?

Comment: yes it is fixed to multiple of 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can do that efficiently in a single process, so I suggest to do a loop like

```
for (( i=1 ; i < 2000; i+=6 )); do
  j=$((i+5))
  cut -d, -f $i-$j your.csv
done
```

Answer (score 0):

***Python*** solution:

sample input file `test.csv`:

```
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4
G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2,G3,H3,I3,J3,K3,L3,G4,H4,I4,J4,K4,L4
```

***slice_on_6.py*** script:

```
import sys, csv
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fh:  # opening csv file
    reader = list(csv.reader(fh))   # reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile
    cnt = len(reader[0])//6         # number(count) of slices
    for i in range(cnt):
        for l in reader:
            print(','.join(l[i*6:6*(i+1)]))  # outputting each slice from each line consecutively
```

Usage:

```
python slice_on_6.py test.csv
```

The output:

```
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1
G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1
A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2
G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2
A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3
G3,H3,I3,J3,K3,L3
A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4
G4,H4,I4,J4,K4,L4
```

Comment: nice one :) I need the bash version but I like the python one too

Answer (score 0):

There's always the venerable `rs`:

```
rs -c, -T < file.csv | split -l6 --filter='rs -C, -T'
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,
G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1,
A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,
G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2,
```

To remove trailing separators, you can pipe through `sed 's/,$//'`

```
rs -c, -T < file.csv | split -l6 --filter='rs -C, -T' | sed 's/,$//'
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1
G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1
A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2
G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2
```

---

FWIW I don't know why `rs` is adding the trailing separator; it has an option

```
-m      Do not trim excess delimiters from the ends of the output array.
```

which suggests the default *ought* to be to remove it.

Comment: Is `rs` package available on Linux systems?

Comment: @Ikaros it's available in Ubuntu (and I'm assuming other Debian-based systems) via package `rs` - not sure about other distros

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `sed` tool as shewn:
The basic theme being that, as a first step, we slurp the file in the pattern space.

Next we apportion the first 6 elements then print that portion out and move that line to the back of the pattern space (after sawing off the printed portion).

Rinse & repeat the above process for the now leading line in the pattern space.

This process stops when the pattern space is left with just the last portion 
of the last line, at which point we just let `sed` print it out after
stripping away the leading newline.

The portions are 6 csv fields and the total number of fields in each line is 
an integer multiple of 6 and each line has the same number of fields.

```
sed -e '
   $!{
      s/$/,/
      N;s/^/\n/;D
   }

   s/^\([^,]*,\n\{0,1\}\)\{6\}/&\n/
   s/\n\n/\n/
   s/,\n/\n/

   P

   y/\n_/_\n/
   s/^[^_]*_//
   s/^\([^_]*\)_\(.*\)/_\2_\1/
   y/\n_/_\n/

   /\n.*\n/D
   s/.*\n//
' yourfile.csv
```

---

## Results

```
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1
G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1
A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2
G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2
```